# Populate WPF TreeView with items in a structure that is not present in underlying data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a single list of objects of different types that I want to present in a WPF TreeView. Some of the objects should be children of other objects, but I don't want the parent objects to have to maintain their own list of the children. I have tried to do this by implementing a property that returns an IEnumerator for the subitems in that group, and binding that as the ItemsSource, but it doesn't seem to work. I've created the following to demonstrate the problem.

CS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Items MyItems;
        private int NextGroupId = 0;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyItems = new Items();
            tvMain.ItemsSource = MyItems.ItemList;
        }
        private void btnNewGroup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyItems.Add(new ItemGroup(MyItems)
            {
                Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                GroupId = NextGroupId
            });
            NextGroupId++;
        }
        private void btnNewSubItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyItems.Add(new SubItem(MyItems)
            {
                Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                GroupId = (tvMain.SelectedItem as ItemGroup).GroupId
            });
        }

        private void tvMain_SelectedItemChanged(object sender,
            RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            btnNewSubItem.IsEnabled = tvMain.SelectedItem is ItemGroup;
        }
    }
    public class Items
    {
        private ObservableCollection<BaseItem> _ItemList;
        public ObservableCollection<BaseItem> ItemList { get { return _ItemList; } }
        public Items()
        {
            _ItemList = new ObservableCollection<BaseItem>();
        }
        public void Add(BaseItem I)
        {
            _ItemList.Add(I);
        }
    }
    public class BaseItem
    {
        protected Items _List;
        public BaseItem(Items List)
        {
            _List = List;
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
    }
    public class ItemGroup : BaseItem
    {
        public ItemGroup(Items _List)
            : base(_List) { }
        public IEnumerator Children
        {
            get
            {
                return _List.ItemList
                    .OfType<SubItem>()
                    .Where(SI => SI.GroupId == this.GroupId)
                    .GetEnumerator();
            }
        }
    }
    public class SubItem : BaseItem
    {
        public SubItem(Items _List)
            : base(_List) { }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:self="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView x:Name="tvMain" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="273" Margin="50,25,0,0" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="265" 
                  SelectedItemChanged="tvMain_SelectedItemChanged">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:ItemGroup}" 
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:SubItem}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
        <Button x:Name="btnNewGroup" Content="New Group" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="336,142,0,0" 
                Click="btnNewGroup_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNewSubItem" Content="New SubItem" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Margin="336,185,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" 
                Click="btnNewSubItem_Click" IsEnabled="False"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

To be clear, I want the SubItems to appear as children of the ItemGroup with the same GroupId. What is the best approach, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a few significant changes in your code:

1. Firstly,  `Items.ItemList` should contain only elements of type `ItemGroup`. Now it contains also elements of type `SubItem` and they are displayed in a tree view as parents. It is not what we want to achieve.
2. However, in order to keep track of all items we need another collection `Items.AllItems`.
3. `ItemGroup.Children` property should be modified to use `Items.AllItems` collection instead of `Items.ItemList`.
4. Finally we need to inform a tree view when a new sub item was created. We will use `INotifyPropertyChanged` to do so.

Here is a working code. However, please note that it is not a production code. I changed only what was absolutely necessary. The purpose of it is only to show you an idea.

You should be also aware that this kind of solution might be slower in comparison to the approach when parent objects have their own lists of children. It will depend on the number of items in a tree view.

```
public class Items
{
    public List<BaseItem> AllItems { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<BaseItem> ItemList { get; private set; }

    public Items()
    {
        ItemList = new ObservableCollection<BaseItem>();
        AllItems = new List<BaseItem>();
    }

    public void Add(BaseItem item)
    {
        AllItems.Add(item);

        if (item is ItemGroup)
            ItemList.Add(item);
        else
            AllItems.OfType<ItemGroup>().Single(i => i.GroupId == item.GroupId).Notify();
        }
    }

public class ItemGroup : BaseItem, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ItemGroup(Items _List): base(_List) { }

    public IEnumerator Children
    {
        get
        {
            return _List.AllItems
                .OfType<SubItem>()
                .Where(SI => SI.GroupId == this.GroupId)
                .GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public void Notify()
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Children)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to accept Michal's answer because it showed me what I was doing wrong and how to fix it. I have actually found a different solution that I prefer, though, since it does not require an extra collection:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Items MyItems;
        private int NextGroupId = 0;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyItems = new Items();
            tvMain.ItemsSource = MyItems.Groups as IEnumerable;
        }
        private void btnNewGroup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyItems.Add(new ItemGroup(MyItems)
            {
                Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                GroupId = NextGroupId
            });
            NextGroupId++;
        }
        private void btnNewSubItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyItems.Add(new SubItem(MyItems)
            {
                Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                GroupId = (tvMain.SelectedItem as ItemGroup).GroupId
            });
        }

        private void tvMain_SelectedItemChanged(object sender,
            RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            btnNewSubItem.IsEnabled = tvMain.SelectedItem is ItemGroup;
        }
    }
    public class Items
    {
        public ObservableCollection<BaseItem> ItemList { get; private set; }
        public ICollectionView Groups { get; private set; }
        public Items()
        {
            ItemList = new ObservableCollection<BaseItem>();
            Groups = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemList);
            Groups.Filter = item => item is ItemGroup;
        }
        public void Add(BaseItem item)
        {
            ItemList.Add(item);
            if (item is SubItem)
                ItemList
                    .OfType<ItemGroup>()
                    .Where(g => g.GroupId == item.GroupId)
                    .Single()
                    .NotifyPropertyChanged("Children");
        }
    }
    public class BaseItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected Items _List;
        public BaseItem(Items List)
        {
            _List = List;
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
    public class ItemGroup : BaseItem
    {
        public ItemGroup(Items _List)
            : base(_List) { }
        public IEnumerator Children
        {
            get
            {
                return _List.ItemList
                    .OfType<SubItem>()
                    .Where(SI => SI.GroupId == this.GroupId)
                    .GetEnumerator();
            }
        }
    }
    public class SubItem : BaseItem
    {
        public SubItem(Items _List)
            : base(_List) { }
    }
}
```